# Hide the full screen button in html5 video in Safari using shadow dom

Tags: css, html5-video, shadow-dom

I want to hide the full screen button in HTML5 video control in Safari browser. I have found the shadow dom element `<div class="controls-bar top-left" role="group">...</div>` which contains the controls of the full-screen button. But I don't find any way to apply css to those elements. In debug mode, I apply css runtime which is working fine. But I don't know how to write css query for shadow dom elements. Is there any way to apply css to shadow dom elements? I wrote the below css to hide the button but couldn't work.

```
<style>
.media-controls.inline.uses-ltr-user-interface-layout-direction > .controls-bar.top-left {display : none;}
</style>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can't test it right now but I found the pseudo selector for shadow dom elements, like such:
video::-webkit-media-controls

So you'd have to replace "." with "::-" or "::-webkit-"

Lemme know if this works. Sorry if this is a little late...